# Apache NetBeans' GUI designer for JFrame forms throws exception when adding a swing menu bar

Tags: macos, java, netbeans, ant, swing

## Background

Recently, I created a new NetBeans project using `New project -> Java with Ant -> Java Application`, and subsequently created a new jFrame form, by right-clicking the package icon ([here's what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oIqrC.png)), then selected `New -> JFrame form`. After that, I started adding swing components from the `Palette` tab.

## Issue

When I tried to add a `Menu Bar` under `Swing Menus`, the component was added to the frame. However, a stacktrace was printed directly onto the entire frame, making it impossible to see any components on the frame.
The stacktrace reads:

```
The following exception has been thrown during painting of the form. Use the Navigator window to fix or remove
the problematic component.
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "javax.swing.border.Border.paintBorder(java.awt.Component,
java.awt.Graphics, int, int, int, int)" because the return value of "com.apple.laf.AquaMenuPainter $RecyclableBorder.get(" is
null
at java.desktop/com.apple.laf.AquaMenuPainter.paintMenuBarBackground(AquaMenuPainter.java:149)
at java.desktop/com.apple.laf.AquaMenuBarUl.paint(AquaMenuBarUl.java:88)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.ComponentUl.update(ComponentUl.java:161)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paintComponent(Component.java:852)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Component.java:1128)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Component.java:961)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Component.java:1137)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.JLayeredPane.paint(LayeredPane.java:586)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.jComponent.paintChildren(Component.java:961)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Component.java:1137)
at java.desktop/java.awt.GraphicsCallback$PaintCallback.run(GraphicsCallback.java:39)
at java.desktop/sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runOneComponent(SunGraphicsCallback.java:75)
at java.desktop/sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runComponents(SunGraphicsCallback.java:112)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.paint(Container.java:2005)
atorg.netbeans.modules.form.fakepeer.FakePeerContainer.paint(FakePeerContainer.java:64)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Component.java:975)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paintUComponent.java:1137)
at org.netbeans.modules.form.ComponentLayer$DesignerPanel.paint(ComponentLayer.java:165)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Component.java:961)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Component.java:1137)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildrenUComponent.java:961)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Component.java:1137)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Component.java:961)
at org.netbeans.modules.form.FormDesigner$1.paintChildren(FormDesigner.java:195)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Component.java:1137)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.JLayeredPane.paint(LayeredPane.java:586)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Component.java:961)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paintUComponent.java:1137)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.JViewport.paint(Viewport.java:736)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.jComponent.paintChildren(Component.java:961)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Component.java:1137)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Component.java:961)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Component.java:1137)
atjava.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Component.java:961)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Component.java:1137)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Component.java:961)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Component.java:1137)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.JLayer.paint(Layer.java:476)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.LayerUl.paint(LayerUl.java:85)
at org.netbeans.core.multiview.SplitLayerUl.paint(SplitLayerUl.java:134)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.ComponentUl.update(ComponentUl.java:161)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paintComponent(Component.java:852)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.JLayer.paint(Layer.java:471)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Component.java:961)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Component.java:1137)
at iava.desktop/iavax.swina.IComponent.paintChildren(IComponent.iava:961)
```

There may be more lines in the stacktrace, but when I tried to scroll down (so that the menu bar was no longer visible on the `Design` tab), the stacktrace disappears and all other components appeared. When I scroll back up, the stacktrace reappears and all other components disappeared again.
Here's [what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t8aXc.jpg) (the highlighted orange component is the menu bar).

## Previous Investigations

I have previously searched other related problems, including:

- [This post on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23201030/what-is-a-look-and-feel-that-is-compatible-with-mac)
- [This post on GitHub](https://github.com/Col-E/Recaf/issues/36)
- [This post on Oracle Communities](https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/1366496/execption-has-been-thrown-during-painting-of-the-form/p2)

Unfortunately, no solutions that I can find worked to solve the issue.

## System Information

Here is my system information according to NetBeans `About` menu item:

```
Product Version: Apache NetBeans IDE 15
Java: 18.0.2.1; Java HotSpot (TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.0.2.1+1-1
Runtime: Java(M) SE Runtime Environment 18.0.2.1+1-1
System: Mac OS X version 12.4 running on x86_64; UTF-8; en_CN (nb)
User directory: /Users/bryan351018/Library/Application Support/NetBeans/15
Cache directory: /Users/bryan351018/Library/Caches/NetBeans/15
```

And here is the output of `java --version` on the command line:

```
java 18.0.2.1 2022-08-18
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 18.0.2.1+1-1)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 18.0.2.1+1-1, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Comment: Why are you not asking this on the Apache NetBeans forum?

Comment: Because Apache NetBeans doesn't have an official forum, and this issue seems to be system-specific (I have seen people put menu bars on their computers, and they were fine).

Answer (score 0):

## Answer

Go to `Options -> Appearance -> Look and Feel`, and change the `Preferred Look and Feel` to `Mac OS X`, then restart Apache NetBeans.

## Comment on this answer

This is a solution, but it seems like a temporary one, as the bright colors of this look and feel are not very peaceful to human eyes.